# Iterate over a block from a parsed JSON in Terraform to create a Map

Tags: json, terraform

I need to iterate over a block that is parsed from a JSON file to create a Map block.
I have multiple JSON files and both the keys and the values are dynamic (can change from one JSON to another).

The parsing is performed via a jsondecode() function.

This is the block from the JSON:

```
    "tags": {
      "repo": "ingestion",
      "cluster": "big"
  }
```

And what I'm trying to get after the parsing should be something like that:

```
tags {
        repo = "ingestion"
        cluster = "big"
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The typical design for a tags mapping in most existing Terraform providers I'm familiar with is for it to be an argument that expects a map value, which means you can just assign a value of a suitable type directly using arbitrary expressions:

```
locals {
  data = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/example.json"))
}

resource "example" "example" {
  # ...

  tags = local.data.tags
}
```

If you are using a provider that considers `tags` to be a nested object (presented as a block) rather than as a value then it would need to declare as part of its schema which arguments it expects, and you would therefore need to assign values to each of those arguments separately:

```
  tags {
    repo    = local.data.tags.repo
    cluster = local.data.tags.cluster
  }
```

That would be quite an unusual provider configuration design, since it would require the provider itself to fix a particular set of tag names rather than allowing them to be decided by you in your configuration. Therefore I expect the first example above is the one that will work, but I've included the second one for completeness because you didn't mention in your question which provider and which resource type from that provider you are using.